# Check if the variable has any whitespace in the first 10 characters

Tags: php, string

What is the best way to check if the string has any spaces in the first 10 characters?

```
$value = "cdjfvdkvnfkjvnfjnbjfnjn";
```

Comment: Use `strpos()` with `substr()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
if (strpos(substr($string, 0, 1), ' ') !== FALSE) {
    // has whitespace
}
```

Or [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match):

```
if(preg_match('/\s/', substr($string, 0, 10))) {
    // has whitespace
}
```

The advantage of `preg_match()` over `strpos()` is that it can detect *any* kind of whitespace not just space characters. `\s` is a shorthand representation for the character class `[\r\n\t\f ]`.

Comment: I would have given the same answer as you but isn't Sagar's solution more elegant here? `ctype_*` functions are nice but rarely used. (At least by me)

Comment: @hek2mgl: Indeed. But `preg_match` in this case is likely to be faster (especially with long strings) since it doesn't require the whole string to be scanned. It stops the search when the engine detects the first whitespace character. I'm not sure if that's how `ctype_space` works, but anyhow it is definitely a useful function.

Comment: `ctype_*()` [functions](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/ctype/ctype.c) internally calling a macro and do not scan the whole string. However, I now read the documentation of that function again and see that `ctype_string()` checks if all(!) characters in string are whitespace.. This will not work here.. So your answer is the still the right solution here even if `ctype` functions are nice.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`ctype_space()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php):

```
if (ctype_space($value)) {

}
```

Comment: I was wondering, how does this solve the problem? It says in the documentation that `Checks if all of the characters in the provided string, text, creates whitespace.` meaning, that if there are any non-whitespace characters, it returns false.

What I understood from the original question, he wants to know if there is 1-10 whitespaces within the first 10 characters.